# Graph Laplacians, Riemannian manifolds, and object collisions

Tags: graph-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry, spectral-graph-theory, image-processing

To preface this question, I am a part-time game developer and full-time optimization fiend.

I am working on object collisions at the moment and many resources I have found online are more-or-less just iterative methods that iterate over every vertex of two object meshes to check for collisions. Obviously, this is not viable for highly detailed meshes and is the reason that collision meshes are often simplified versions of objects' models.

While looking for a work-around to the standard iterative methods, I fell down the mathematical rabbit-hole and landed on topologies and graph theory. From what I understand, a model is ultimately just a manifold in 3-dimensional space. Additionally, the nature of object meshes (sets of vertices connected by edges) allows any model can be represented as a graph, and as a result, any model can be used to construct a graph Laplacian.

The conclusion slide from [this slideshow presentation by Radu Horaud](https://csustan.csustan.edu/%7Etom/Clustering/GraphLaplacian-tutorial.pdf) from the INRIA research center states that spectral graph embedding based on the graph Laplacian "allows links between graphs and Riemannian manifolds."

Putting these things together with the concept of the intersection of manifolds gave me the idea to completely do away with the iterative methods of collision detection in favor of a one-time check for an intersection (2-dimensional manifold with non-zero area) between two object meshes. The creation of graph Laplacians, spectral graph embedding, and Riemannian manifolds would all happen at compile-time leaving only the intersection check needing to be calculated in between frames. This would greatly reduce the time needed to detect object collisions and massively increase the level of detail possible for collision meshes.

My line of thinking is probably completely wrong, but is something like this possible?

What does Radu Horaud mean that graphs can be linked with manifolds? How would that be achieved? How then could two manifolds (or whatever that "link" is that Radu mentions) be used to determine an area of intersection?

Comment: I am quite familiar with mesh Laplacians and a bit less with collision detection, and I don't quite see how Laplacians could allow to improve current collision detection methods.

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with topological mathematics, but my idea is to use spectral graph embedding and mesh Laplacians to link discrete meshes to continuous manifolds, then use the manifold equations to calculate whether or not the objects are intersecting. The manifold calculations would be slow, but caching those ahead of time, then making a single intersection calculation at runtime would be faster than iterating through every vertex of two objects with very high vertex counts. However, I don't have the first clue on how to go from mesh Laplacians to Riemannian manifolds to test this theory.

Comment: Deciding if two manifolds given by equations intersect isn't fast in general. And collision detection doesn't iterate through all vertices in a brute force way, there are faster algorithms

Comment: I don't expect it to be fast in general and I understand that there are spatial partitioning algorithms that make collision detection faster, but that's not what I am asking here.

I am asking if it is possible to calculate the intersection of two manifolds created from a discrete Laplacian, and how that could be done. I'd appreciate if we could stay on topic. My reasons for doing so are only contextually relevant.

Comment: no, at least i'm not seeing how spectral embedding could help computing intersections

Comment: Let's take it one step at a time. Could you explain what Radu means when he says that spectral graph embedding links graph Laplacians with Riemannian manifolds and how this is done?

Comment: i would assume he means that the machinery/theory around laplacians, which was developped for manifolds, can be used for graphs as well. But this is well known since about 35 years, it's not research level stuff.

Comment: probably if you want to gain insight you should read more papers and/or ask on stackexchange